# Map doesn't display on Mixare app

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I had change API key in `MixMap.java` like this on https://github.com/mixare/mixare/blob/79080d2a2adf346724cc8669b4b41f430084fcde/src/org/mixare/MixMap.java

`Line: 100` with my API key

Ex:  `setMapView(new MapView(this, "AIzaSyA4liteNAjUkdzwFPMZHqxWfj13UasD_jg"));`

but there still not showing a map

anyone can help ?

ps.sorry for my bad language

Comment: have you created key with your keystore or debug.keystore?

Comment: do u mean a this , or not ?

Key for Android apps (with certificates)API key: 
AIzaSyA4liteNAjUkdzwFPMZHqxWfj13UasD_jg
Android apps: 
0A:0C:2C:E8:77:57:9B:28:79:3D:AF:5E:B0:85:AC:2C:88:1E:D4:02;com.mixare

in google APIs console

Answer (score 0):

you should using google map v2 in mixare app, API key is in the Manifest.xml

like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="your_API_key"/>
```